# SQL issue aggregating values based on time

Tags: sql, time, aggregation

I need a running total of value 1 and value 2.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Time | Plus Value | Minus Value 2 | 
0         30           10             
10        20           15
15        10           20
...
```

I would like to be able to get the following table

```
Time | Plus Value | Minus Value 2 | Total
0         30           10             20           
10        20           15             25
15        10           20             15
...
```

I would like to be able to select something like this

```
select time, plus_value, minus_value(sum(plus_value) - sum(minus_value)) as total
from table
where time <= time
```

How can I do this? I am forced to group by time which then does not give me the desired result.

Comment: It depends on what RDBMS you are using. MySQL? SQL Server? Pick your variety and then search Stack Overflow for `running-total`

Answer (score 4):

```
select time,
       plus_value,
       minus_value,
       sum(plus_value - minus_value) over(order by time rows unbounded preceding) as total
from table
```

Comment: That the OP's RDBMS can do this is a significant assumption. At least mention where and when this will or won't work?

Comment: Thanks to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) this is tested on SQL Server 2012, Oracle 11g R2 and PostgreSQL 9.1.3. It might work on other DBMS as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I actually came up with another one on my own however I am unable to post for another 6 hours. I'm sure most will have lost interested by then. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your where clause: `where time <= time`?

Anyways, I believe that your query could be implemented like:

```
select time, plus_value, minus_value, (plus_value - minus_value) as total
from table;
```

Comment: No, check your calculation against the example data.  The OP wants a running total...

Comment: Ahhh..my mistake.  Maybe you can make use of SQL variables: DECLARE @total; SET @total = 0; SELECT time, plus_value, minus_value, (@total + plus_value - minus_value) AS total FROM table; @ total = total;